# How can I execute a Python script from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome

I have written a module in python which performs some function.

I then created a Google Chrome extension which makes use of JSON and javascript.

Now when I click on the extension I want it to execute the python program which is stored on my hard disk and display the output on the browser again.

Is there a way in which I can do this??

Comment: Is the point of the extension to use chrome? Or are you just looking for an environment for your application? I am doing something quite similar using the Adobe Air SDK, which lets you call python scripts bundled with your app. It is a javascript / html environment which allows you to work with you local hard disk and local sockets / resources.

Comment: But I want it to be made available on the browser. Adobe Air SDK lets you create an interface on the browser?

Comment: No, it won't allow you to make it avaiable in another browser. It has it's own internal webkit based browser, which is installed as an air app or native application.

Comment: I have already created the plug in.. I just want to send data from the current web page to my python program residing on my hard disk . Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: No experience with chrome extensions, so can't help there unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repeated :

[Calling Python from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901093/calling-python-from-javascript)

Here you have some answers, Pyjamas is probably the best option in your case

Comment: I tried using pyjamas but it tries to convert the entire python script into a javascript. But my pyhton script uses NLTK and other such packages and hence the JS script gives errors

Comment: Then I think that there is no option , google-chrome doesn't provide a python interpreter and I suppose that no extension can do that job. Nonetheless you can do it for mozilla firefox with http://pyxpcomext.mozdev.org/

Answer (score 2):

Probably a late reply but a possible solution is to make your python script act as a server and let the browser plugin interact with it.

Answer (score 1):

forgive me if i'm incorrect on infinite proportions.

I believe that JavaScript is executed in a sandboxed/ isolated environment. Therefore you cannot invoke a python interpreter* or any other executable residing on the system.

*unless the interpreter itself were written in javascript.

Comment: Oh okay. Can anyone suggest any other way of doing it? I am trying it since 2 weeks and I am not reaching anywhere :-(